# How to disable/enable short messaging on android phone on basis of some flag

Tags: android

I'm looking for an app that disables sending or receiving or both - of SMS messages from a android device . Once the app is installed it checks a web url for a boolean value 0 or 1, if it's zero, sms is disabled, else it's enabled.

Can anyone guide me from where to start ?Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a BroadcastReceiver for incoming SMS and use `this.abortBroadcast();` to abort its further processing:

Inside you manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
   </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Implementation of the receiver:

```
 public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        ...
        this.abortBroadcast();
      }
    }
}
```

However - it is not possible to abort an outgoing SMS that way. Please note that if more than one BroadcastReceivers are registered, the one with the highest priority (`android:priority`) will be processed first.

Comment: Do u know how to put password on messaging inbox? like go Sms pro ..hwo can we do that with in our android code?

Comment: The answer to this question is not simple and would take pages of code/explanation. In short yes you can - but you have to move messages from the sms store into an own ContentProvider. Here you have "full control"

Answer (score 2):

Imho you cant disable SMS receiving/sending at all, but you can catch the SMS received Broadcast Intent.

The SMS received Broadcast Intent is a ordered Broadcast, it will be delivered to all Broadcast Receivers in order of the Priority defined in the Receiver.

If you register a Broadcast Receiver with Priority 0 you can catch the SMS Broadcast and cancel it.

Keep in mind that other SMS Apps can also register with Priority 0 the behavior is undefined for same priority values. Also the SMS is received anyway, you only hide the Resulting Notifications/Ringtone.

---

Another approach would be to set the SMS Central Number to some invalid Values, required a rooted Phone though

Comment: thnx for your help...another idea is to put password on messaging inbox like goSms pro in android market....u had any idea how to do that ?